# Android Error - Error inflating class

Tags: java, android

I am just starting with android development through Java (i have only previously used phonegap).

I created my first hello world project with a simple form text field and send button, and it won't run.

My error log is below:

```
12-06 20:31:11.482: E/AndroidRuntime(32656): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.thesurvivor2299/com.example.thesurvivor2299.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
12-06 20:31:11.482: E/AndroidRuntime(32656): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 

Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
12-06 22:32:31.304: W/ResourceType(804): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0201f2 (t=1 e=498) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
12-06 22:32:31.305: W/ResourceType(804): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0201f3 (t=1 e=499) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
12-06 22:32:31.305: W/ResourceType(804): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0201f4 (t=1 e=500) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
12-06 22:32:31.580: W/ResourceType(804): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020609 (t=1 e=1545) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
12-06 22:32:31.581: W/ResourceType(804): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020627 (t=1 e=1575) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
12-06 22:32:31.624: W/ResourceType(804): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0201f2 (t=1 e=498) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
12-06 22:32:31.624: W/ResourceType(804): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0201f3 (t=1 e=499) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
12-06 22:32:31.624: W/ResourceType(804): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0201f4 (t=1 e=500) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
12-06 22:32:31.646: W/ResourceType(804): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020609 (t=1 e=1545) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
12-06 22:32:31.646: W/ResourceType(804): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020627 (t=1 e=1575) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
```

As there are a lot of files, i'm not sure which would be best to provide the code of. Let me know which file, and i'll copy the code in here.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@style/AppTheme"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textWebEditText"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:text="Send" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I can post any of the code if it helps

Comment: As You may read in Your error message there is problem with XML file. So You can post layout for MainActivity.

Comment: This is java file, not XML. You have an error in activity_main.xml file

Comment: You don't close the RelativeLayout in your activity_main.xml

Comment: the webite hid it for some reason. It is there in the file

Comment: The stacktrace should include more information why it failed. Something like "caused by BigProblemWithXYZException..."

Comment: Then post a bit more of stack, best if You post all red lines.

Comment: I do get "Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.example.thesurvivor2299' on port 8600" and nothing else before it crashes

Comment: thats all i get in the console

Comment: `Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.example.thesurvivor2299`

Is this a joke? Too soon, man.

Comment: @pedantic its a test app to learn android, it was the only name that came to mind :p

Comment: @Wayneio I'm a mighty, mighty man and I'm young and in my prime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This type of error can be fixed by going to the file `R.java` and search for the error entry e.g `0x7f0201f2` from your log. It would correspond to a variable. And if you look at the containing method of this entry it will tell you whether it is a string, id, dimen etc.
Then you can just search for this variable in your project and find if it has been declared in   your resource files.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close `<RelativeLayout>` tag in Your layout.

Add `</RelativeLayout>` at the end of xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Close the `RelativeLayout` tag with `</RelativeLayout>`