# Android Failure getting entry for

Tags: android

Okay, so I'm getting this error:

```
W/ResourceType﹕ Failure getting entry for 0x01080ac1 (t=7 e=2753) (error -75)
```

It happens about every single time I dynamically inflate a layout, and then add it. Using the debugger I've pinpointed the location to:

```
    /**
 * Create a new ScrollableVerticalListView.
 *
 * @param context   the context to create the LinearLayout in.
 * @param fullWidth The width to set on the LinearLayout.
 */
public ScrollableVerticalListView(Context context, final int fullWidth) {
    super(context);
    setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    innerLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    innerLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    MainActivity.getInstance().runOnUiThread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    setWidth(fullWidth);
                }
            });
    ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(context);//<--No error in logcat
    scrollView.addView(innerLinearLayout);//<--Error in logcat
    super.addView(scrollView);
}
```

This class extends LinearLayout. Any ideas on how to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 2):

Try tracking the resource id 0x01080ac1 in the project, at the R.java. To check if the path of the resource is correct. Found this from an answer in this post [Android Error - Error inflating class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433115/android-error-error-inflating-class)

Edit: Quote of the answer from the provided link:

> This type of error can be fixed by going to the file R.java and search
>   for the error entry e.g 0x7f0201f2 from your log. It would correspond
>   to a variable. And if you look at the containing method of this entry
>   it will tell you whether it is a string, id, dimen etc. Then you can
>   just search for this variable in your project and find if it has been
>   declared in your resource files.